# Recommended best Security Practices for Outlook Add-in Web App hosting in Cloud (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Outlook Add-in Web App could be hosted in Cloud(AWS) but what's the authentication mechanism to make Web App secured in cloud and not accessible by any unauthorized Users by directly accessing URL of Web App.

Manifest.xml has 'SourceLocation' element to specify URL of default landing page but no provision to explicitly define authentication to make more securable.

It would be appreciable if someone could share steps involved in configuration, Authentication and best practices to be implemented while hosting Web App under AWS in order to follow best security practices.

Answer (score 0):

Please use authentication methods to verify users accessing the web page, if the contents are sensitive.
You can use username and passwords, for example.

Furthermore, if you want to authenticate users there are various ways.
Please check out the article : [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication#:~:text=Exchange%20user%20identity%20tokens%20provide,an%20authorization%20for%20future%20requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication#:%7E:text=Exchange%20user%20identity%20tokens%20provide,an%20authorization%20for%20future%20requests).

This will verify the user, but won't restrict them from accessing your web page.